# MLE Estimator for paratmer of piece-wise uniform distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, continuity, variance, estimation, maximum-likelihood

My question relates to this thread here: [How to find MLE of this piecewise pdf?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3216935/how-to-find-mle-of-this-piecewise-pdf) On answer submitted by @StubbornAtom and @Riccardo, the expression used, doesn't that require pdf to be continuous, Is it valid expression in this case ?

Also for such an estimator how can we find variance of estimator? As it cannot be calculated by fisher information or the Delta method since the observation x are not involved in likelihood function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a step back and think about sufficiency, before you can consider estimation.

Recall that, loosely speaking, a statistic is sufficient for a parameter $\theta$ if it does not discard any information about the parameter that is present in the sample.  The joint density is
$$f(\boldsymbol x) = \theta^{n_1} (1-\theta)^{n_2},$$
where $$n_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb 1 (0 \le x_i \le 1), \\
n_2 = n - n_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb 1 (1 < x_i \le 2).$$
So we note that the likelihood $\mathcal L(\theta \mid \boldsymbol x)$ **is** a function of the sample $\boldsymbol x$, as it must be.  Just because we wrote it in terms of functions $n_1, n_2$ of $\boldsymbol x$, does not mean it no longer depends on the sample.  This is your first misunderstanding.

Then, by the factorization theorem, the joint density may be written as
$$(\boldsymbol x) = h(\boldsymbol x) g(T(\boldsymbol x) \mid \theta)$$ where $$T(\boldsymbol x) = n_1, \\ g(T \mid \theta) = \theta^T (1-\theta)^{n - T}, \\ h(\boldsymbol x) = 1.$$  Thus $n_1$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$.  This means that any estimator for $\theta$ that does not discard information about $\theta$ can be written as a function of the sufficient statistic $n_1$, and this property is satisfied by the MLE $\hat \theta = n_1/n$.

Second, MLEs can be derived for discrete distributions, as well as families of distributions for which the [parameter space is itself discrete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4175766/maximum-likelihood-when-parameter-space-is-discrete/4175880#4175880).  If you are not aware of this, you need to review statistical estimation, as this is a basic concept.

The variance of $\hat \theta$ is straightforward, as $n_1$ is binomially distributed with parameters $n$ and $\theta$.  This follows from the fact that $\Pr[0 \le X_i \le 1] = \theta$ for each $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$.  So $$\operatorname{Var}[\hat \theta] = \frac{\operatorname{Var}[n_1]}{n^2} = \frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{n}.$$